# Serve DNS based on query origination

Tags: google-cloud-dns

what options do I have to answer DNS queries based on location of the query?  E.g. if the query is from .fr, return a separate A record vs. port 53 query from .us.

Comment: You can try [gdnsd](http://gdnsd.org/), but it's not related to google-cloud-dns

Comment: Instead of resolving different IP addresses for the same A record, you can use a global IP address that is a special IP that can intelligently route users based on proximity. Fore more information, visit the Cross-region load balancing artcile: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/#https_load_balancing